# Using @variable := from mysql in delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

My question is; how can I use `:=` (assign values in mysql) to work in delphi?

Here is my example :

```
create TEMPORARY TABLE if not EXISTS new
SELECT date, price, kat, tipe, ready, use, 
if(tipe = '0', @x := use, (@x := @x - (ready-use)))as balance,
@result := ready + @x as HSL,
if (@result <=0, ready, ready+@x) as sata... and script complete..
```

My problem is; delphi cannot except `:=` from mysql.

Comment: Surely the entire string should be enclosed in quotation marks - in which case Delphi won't regard := as the assignment operator but rather two characters in a string.

Comment: Coba pake case when di mysqlnya. soalnya kalo itu masih berbentuk string query bagaimanapun ga bisa diexec oleh delphi

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use ":"  set Paramcheck to false.